# What do “torment” and “rough up” here means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

torment means torture either physically or mentally?
Rough us up means beat up physically?

Freed rebel fighter Denis Balbukov said: "I want to eat fried potatoes and talk to my relatives."

But he added: "I will go back to fighting. It was all right once we were moved to the detention centre, but to begin with, they really **tormented** and **roughed us up**."

Answer (score 1):

*rough up* is physical violence.

*torment* can be both physical and mental.

Given that in the text both words are used, I think that *torment* refers to the mental anguish caused by the captors (e.g. waking you up all the time), while *roughed us up* refers to the violence they endured.